# Azure Service Principal Token 401

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

I have a web api (.Net 6) deployed to Azure App Services. Its an authorized api and I have a service principal (or App Registration) created for the web api which has Azure AD User.Read permissions. I use postman to Generate a token to access this api to test deployed environments. My Authentication config looks like this where "Options" are defined in my appSettings.

[image]

And my Postman request to get the Token is :

[image]

Strange thing is that I get a 401 when I send a GET to the Azure endpoint but everything works fine locally. I have used the App Logs feature on Azure and looked anywhere I could find debug hints but this is the only clue I have right now :

[image]
What should I recheck and how can I solve this? I do not validate audiences in my .Net Code and upto last week everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

- I was able to access the azure ad attached web Api where I first created boiler-plate code given by visual studio.
- After that, click on the `Add a service dependency` button in the opened tab. Then click on the `Microsoft Identity platform` to add dependency which will help us authorize using azure ad.

[image]

[image]

- Then, select an app register from the list if you have created an app registration or you can create a new registration by clicking on the `create new`  button.

[image]

- Then select `add graph permission` and then go next after that a secret will be generated in you add registration.

[image]

[image]

- Continue to select next/finish util the process is finished.

[image]

- Now create a new app registration in azure portal and then under `authentication` tab of you newly created app registration click on  `add platform`

[image]

- Now click on `Single page Application` then a popup will open where you will have to add a callback URL `https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback`

[image]

[image]

Please select the following option too.

[image]

- Now under the `api permission`  tab click on `add permission`  a popup will appear where you have to go under the `my api` section and then select the previous app registration used with the web Api.

[image]

[image]

- Now that we have configured everything we can now focus on the postman where first create a new tab add your URL and then click on the `authorization` tab then select `oauth 2.0` in the `type` option and select `requests in headers` in `add auth data to` tab.

[image]

- Now fill the subsequent form but first make sure that the `grant type`   is set to `Implicit`

[image]

- Then you add the `client_id` , `auth_url` and `scope`all these values are available in the azure portal.

client id :

[image]

auth url:

[image]

scope:

[image]

Now click on `Get new Access token`

- This will take you to the browser to login in the azure account and it will ask for permission. Once you grant that permission it will look like this.

[image]

- Now a popup will appear in postman where you will have a token which can be used for auth. Select the token and then option will appear to use it with the Api.

Now you can access your Web Api.

Comment: Thank you! I had lost hope, I will try out these steps and revert. I have a question for the browser interaction part, when I am querying my API through postman these steps might work for me. 
But how can I generate a token programmatically? To use in automated deployments or intg tests for example.